# SNP_POP equivalent in ODI 12C?

Tags: groovy, oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to get the mapping details like expressions used, KM used ,etc. Previously in 11g ,I was able to query it from SNP_POP and SNP_POP_MAPPING. However in 12c these tables are empty. What're the equivalent tables for these two in 12C? 
I am trying to edit the KM's of specific mappings through SNP tables instead of writing a Groovy script.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces have been replaced by mappings in 12c. You will find the mappings metadata in `SNP_MAPPING` and all the tables starting with `SNP_MAP_`. It's a bit more complex than interfaces because there could be a lot more components and multiples target tables.

Here is an example of a query to retrieve the target table names of a mapping : https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2016/02/di-tips-odi12c-repo-query-mapping-target-table/

You can find the repository documentation in this article : [Doc ID 1903225.1 : Oracle Data Integrator 11g and 12c Repository Description](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1903225.1&displayIndex=1)

However I would **strongly recommend not** to change the KMs from the repository. Select statements on the repositories are allowed but DML statement are not supposed to happen and are not supported by Oracle.

A groovy script using the SDK is definitely the way to go. Luckily, it's already written for you : http://www.ateam-oracle.com/getting-groovy-with-odi-upgrades-and-owb-migrations/